# Automatically setting the value of a field based on another with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Using Flask-SQLAlchemy I have a table which looks like this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

I have a [Python library](https://github.com/dimka665/awesome-slugify) which converts the value of some text into a slug like `slugify('Hello World')` to `hello-world`.

Say I was to create a User:

```
user = User('John Smith')
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

I would like the value of `slug` in the `User` table to be `Slugify('John Smith')`.

How would I go about this? Thanks.

Comment: Add `self.slug = slugify(name)` to your `__init__()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As IanAuld said in the comments I should just add `self.slug = slugify(name)` like so:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.slug = slugify(name)
```